# Spring Boot: How to declare a custom repository factory bean

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data

I'm using *Spring Boot (1.3.3)* with annotation-based/JavaConfig configuration on an application.
I have the following repository interface:

```
@RepositoryRestResource(collectionResourceRel = "something", path = "something")
public interface SomethingRepository 
    extends CrudRepository<SomethingRepository, Long> {

}
```

What I would like to do is override the behavior of some methods in the generated repository proxy. The only way I found of doing this is based on what the documentation suggests for adding new custom methods (see: [Adding custom behavior to single repositories](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.single-repository-behaviour)), so I define the following interface:

```
public interface SomethingRepositoryCustom {
    Something findOne(Long id);
}
```

...and I add the corresponding implementation:

```
public SomethingRepositoryImpl extends SimpleJpaRepository<Something, Long> 
    implements SomethingRepositoryCustom {

    public SomethingRepositoryImpl(<Something> domainClass, EntityManager em) {
        super(domainClass, em);
        this.entityManager = em;
    }

    @Override
    public Something findOne(Long id) {
        System.out.println("custom find one");
        // do whatever I want and then fetch the object
        return null;
    }

}
```

Now, if I start the application, I get the following error:

> ... org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to
>   instantiate [com.dummy.repositories.SomethingRepositoryImpl]: No
>   default constructor found; nested exception is
>   java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.dummy.repositories.SomethingRepositoryImpl.() ...

**Question:**
How can I solve the BeanInstantiationException? I'm assuming I need to declare a repository factory bean but I'm not sure how to do so overriding the Spring Boot configuration.

Answer (score 10):

Indeed you have to declare a new FactoryBean in your `@EnableJpaRepositories` annotation:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(value = "your_package",
        repositoryFactoryBeanClass = CustomFactoryBean.class)
public class ConfigurationClass{}
```

CustomFactoryBean.java:

```
public class CustomFactoryBean<R extends JpaRepository<T, I>, T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactoryBean<R, T, I>{

    @Override
    protected RepositoryFactorySupport createRepositoryFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
        return new SimpleJpaExecutorFactory(entityManager);
    }

    /**
     * Simple jpa executor factory
     * @param <T>
     * @param <I>
     */
    private static class SimpleJpaExecutorFactory<T, I extends Serializable> extends JpaRepositoryFactory{

        private EntityManager entityManager;

        /**
         * Simple jpa executor factory constructor
         * @param entityManager entity manager
         */
        public SimpleJpaExecutorFactory(EntityManager entityManager) {
            super(entityManager);
            this.entityManager = entityManager;
        }

        @Override
        protected Object getTargetRepository(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            JpaEntityInformation entityInformation =
                    getEntityInformation(metadata.getDomainType());
            return new SomethingRepositoryImpl<T,I>(entityInformation, entityManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected Class getRepositoryBaseClass(RepositoryMetadata metadata) {
            return SomethingRepositoryImpl.class;
        }
    }
}
```

Then it will be your `SimpleJpaRepository` instance: `SimpleJpaRepositoryImpl` that will be used

Comment: I tried this and it was still trying to instantiate the default constructor for SomethingRepositoryImpl. That's because, by convention, Spring fetches for class names ending in Impl.
I changed the Impl suffix and added the code you provided and it worked.

Comment: Would this approach work if I needed to customize more than one repository?
Looks like you can only define one repositoryFactoryBeanClass in  @EnableJpaRepositories.

Comment: yes because repositoryFactoryBeanClass  allows you to point to your custom SimpleJpaRepository instance wich will be shared by all of your repositories

Comment: OP has not followed up, but I tried it out and it worked as suggested.

Answer (score 2):

From version 1.9, you no longer need to create a new FactoryBean class, instead you can just set the base repository directly.  From [Baeldung](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-method-in-all-repositories):

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "org.baeldung.persistence.dao", 
  repositoryBaseClass = ExtendedRepositoryImpl.class)
public class StudentJPAH2Config {
    // additional JPA Configuration
}

public class ExtendedRepositoryImpl<T, ID extends Serializable>
  extends SimpleJpaRepository<T, ID> implements ExtendedRepository<T, ID> {
    
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public ExtendedRepositoryImpl(JpaEntityInformation<T, ?> 
      entityInformation, EntityManager entityManager) {
        super(entityInformation, entityManager);
        this.entityManager = entityManager;
    }

    // ...
}
```